# Optimise database query to avoid memory issues

Tags: laravel-5, chunks

I have a huge Users table (maybe around 4M rows) and I want to run a monthly Job for checking their last login date and if they have not logged in update user and update isPassive column with true.

```
$users = \DB::table('users')
                   ->whereNull('isPassive')->get();
foreach($users as $user)
{
   if(!$user->wasActive())
   {
      $this_user = (new User)::where('id', $user->id)->first();
      $this_user->isPassive = true;
      $this_user->save();
   }
}
```

I have learned to run jobs with Laravel but this gives me memory issues. Well I can increase the server memory but from what I have read here, increasing the memory is not always the best solution.

I tried the [chunk results](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#chunking-results) but when I use `where()` it just hangs. If I use it without and conditions it works nice though.

I am wondering how would a experienced developer would break this job to use less memory?

Labelled it as Laravel but this is a question for any new programmer may face when learning better manage the memory.

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few issues with your code. First:

```
$this_user = (new User)::where(...)->first();
...
```

This line is running a new query in every iteration of your `foreach` loop, so you're essentially running 4 million additional, unnecessary queries. That query is redundant, since you already have `$user`, and `$this_user` would be the same thing. Change your code as follows:

```
$users = User::whereNull('isPassive')->get();
foreach($users AS $user){
  if(!$user->wasActive()){
    $user->isPassive = true;
    $user->save();
  }
}
```

With that, you cut your queries in half.

Also, I'm not sure what `wasActive()` method does, but if you can move that logic onto your initial query, you can likely remove the loop, running a single `update` statement:

```
DB::table("users")
->whereNull("isPassive")
->where(...) // Apply logic from User wasActive() check
->update(["isPassive" => true]);
```

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Ah @Tim thank you. Did not know that actually I was able to do that. I thought you cannot update a Model if you fetch it with the `get()`. So I was using `->first()`all the time. I will give it a try. Also, `wasAvtive()`just return true or false depending on lastLogin data in the last 90 days :)

Comment: Thank you! I have tried it and really changed a lot. Your advice really makes sense.

Comment: No worries. `DB::table("users")->get()` and `User::get()` don't return a `Collection` of the same thing (`stdClass` vs `User` model), which is why I switched it in my code; so you can call `$user->save()` without having to fetch via `User::first()`. And yeah, adding a check for `lastLogin`, moving it from `wasActive()` will allow you to do this in a single query. Glad I could help though :)